# Are ivars of PFObject subclasses stored in local datastore?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a subclass of `PFObject` called `Session`. This object stores an array of objects as an instance variable. The array contains objects of type `Event`, which is also a subclass of `PFObject`. When I call the `pinInBackground` on the `Session` object to cache it locally, will this array instance var also get cached? I understand that caching standard `PFObjects` stores the data dictionary, but what about subclasses?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS)? It should save variables as long as they are prefixed with `@NSManaged` and you've implemented the subclass properly.

Comment: However, `@NSManaged` doesn't let me give an initial value for variable. Since never explicitly instantiate the class, but rather create it view typecast, how do I assign an initial value to the variable?

Comment: added an answer + a link to another answer that outlines the initial variable problem

Comment: @lightice11, I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980151/how-to-set-an-initial-value-for-nsmanaged-property-pfobject-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @lightice11 above, I realized that this can be achieved by marking instance vars as `@NSManaged`, and they will be saved in the Parse Local Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added the @NSManaged tag to the variable.

Parse will then automatically save changes to the variable, but it does not have a default value. This can be solved in many ways, some of which I [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29923257/4080860).

Comment: How would I overload the `object` method in Swift? I'm not sure that the other methods you talk about would work in my case, as the var is not a part of the data dictionary and is never synced up to Parse, rather it simply a local instance var.