# How to set an initial value for @NSManaged property PFObject Subclass?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsmanagedobject, instance-variables

I have a subclass of `PFObject` called `Attendee`. In this class, there is a instance variable I have called `isFavorite`. Below is its class definition:

```
@NSManaged var isFavorite: Bool
```

This is an instance var that is local to the device and I never sync it up to the server. In addition, I never explicitly instantiate the `Attendee` class, but rather create it by typecasting from `PFObject`. I would like to set the above var to have an initial value of `false`. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isFavorite: Bool {
    get {
        if let isFavorite = self["isFavorite"] as? Bool {
            return isFavorite
        }
        return false //default
    }
    set {
        self["isFavorite"] = newValue
    }
}
```